# Pourquoi y a-t-il « pas » avec « encore » à la forme négative ?

Tags: grammaire, négation

A ma connaissance, il faut omettre « pas » dans une phrase négative lorsqu'un déterminant négatif est utilisé.

> Je veux tout. → Je ne veux rien.
>
> Je connais tout le monde. → Je ne connais personne.
>
> Je suis toujours heureux. → Je ne suis jamais heureux.
>
> Je mange encore des fruits. → Je ne mange plus de fruits.
>
> **J'ai déjà terminé. → Je n'ai pas encore terminé.**

Alors pourquoi utilise-t-on « pas » dans le dernier cas ?

Comment: C'est le même principe (et la même différence) que pour l'anglais "I am **not** done **yet**" vs "I am **not** done". yet -> encore et déjà = already. les deux phrases marchent sans ces deux mots (encore et déjà) mais on peut perdre une information.

Comment: La façon dont ces exemples sont présentés et l'usage de la flèche prête à confusion entre les notions de contraire et de négation. *Je ne veux rien* est le contraire de *je veux tout* et non pas sa négation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to use this answer as a jumping board for others who can answer more precisely (if they choose not to close the question as nearly a duplicate of some others).

Indeed, some "flavours of negation" involve replacing the "vanilla" *pas* and others don't.

> Je ne pense pas. *I don't think.*

You gave some good examples of negations that replace *pas* :

> Je ne pense à rien. *I'm not thinking about anything.*
>
> Je ne pense à personne. *I'm not thinking about anyone.*
>
> Je ne pense jamais. *I never think.*
>
> Je ne pense plus. *I don't think anymore.*

Here are some that don't:

> Non, je ne pense pas non plus. *I don't think either (=besides whatever else I don't do).*
>
> Je ne pense pas du tout à elle. *I don't think about her at all.*
>
> Je ne pense pas encore à ce problème. *I'm not thinking about that problem yet.*

You asked why *pas* is not replaced in cases like these. The real question might be why it is replaced in the others (which are the majority — there are lots more not cited above).

French negation began with *ne*. That was sufficient to negate a verb. Whatever comes after the *ne* began as an adverb to qualify the negation (which is why it follows the verb).

If I recall correctly, *pas*, which as a noun means "a step", was introduced with the sense of "not even one step", that is, "not even a little bit". (Compare its etymology [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/pas) — it only started being used in negatives in the 12th century.)

Gradually, because systematic exaggeration tends to weaken a word, the use of *pas* led to its no longer being emphatic, just becoming part of the default way to negate something. (In formal language, you can still omit it; in familiar language, you can instead drop the less salient *ne* now.)

The question therefore likely has to do with which other negations grew up alongside *pas* historically, as just other qualifiers that could be fitted in instead of *pas* before it was solidified, versus negations that grew up after *pas* was established as a necessary part of the negation. A quick check of [*personne*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/personne), [*jamais*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/jamais), and [*rien*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/rien) suggests that they were contemporary with *pas* as matches for *ne*, whereas *[encore](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/encore)* seems to have examples in the negative from only about 200 years ago, long after *pas* was established.

Another possible line of reasoning is the need to contradict the positive meaning that a word would have without *pas*. Notice that *encore* in the positive usually means *still* or, in some constructions, *again*. It may be that unlike the other terms that are more inherently negative (at least at this point in history), *encore* still needs an explicit *pas* to pick between its meaning. (You'd think that *ne* would serve to distinguish them, but as I mentioned above, *ne* is frequently dropped in familiar speech.)

Again, I invite clarifications/corrections from other editors!

Answer (score 2):

Les trois premiers exemples sont incorrects.

La négation de « je veux tout » n'est pas « je ne veux rien » mais « je ne veux pas tout », ce qui est très différent. La négation de « je ne veux rien » est « je veux quelque chose ».

Pareil pour :

> Je connais tout le monde. → Je ne connais pas tout le monde.
>
> Je suis toujours heureux. → Je ne suis pas toujours heureux.

Les deux derniers exemples montrent des négations correctes et utilisent bien « ne », comme les trois autres après correction.

Answer (score 1):

Oui, on ne met pas 'pas' parce qu'on a déjà fait une négation dans la réponse :
Je veux tout... Pas tout = rien. => je ne veux rien.

. Pas tout le monde => personne

. Pas toujours => jamais  est ici une mauvaise négation  : ne pas être toujours heureux ne veut pas dire 'jamais heureux'. Il faudrait laisser 'pas toujours heureux '.

. Pas 'encore' => plus (du tout) de fruits.

enfin  pour le dernier cas : 'Déjà' exprime un travail terminé en avance par rapport à la question. Le contraire est donc un travail où il faut rajouter encore du temps. 
'Je n'ai pas terminé' est la négation pure, 'encore'  ajoute qu'on va le faire mais avec encore un peu de temps.

Answer (score 0):

D'après moi les cas dans lesquelles il faut omettre 'pas' à la phrase négative sont rares.

Dans ton cas, tu as juste remplacé le 'pas' par un synonyme.

Ci-dessous j'ai mis entre parenthèses les mots qui sont des synonymes de 'pas' :

- Je ne connais (personne). => Je ne connais pas de gens.
- Je ne suis (jamais) heureux. => Je ne suis pas heureux.
- Je ne mange (plus) de fruits. => Je ne mange pas de fruits.

'ne' est une négation et n'as rien à voir avec 'n'ai' qui viens du verbe 'avoir'.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ta dernière phrase : « n'ai », c'est « ne » + la conjugaison du verbe « avoir ».