# Why is the "pas" here left out?

Tags: grammaire, négation

Below is the quote from ***Candide***:

> Tu ne mérites pas d'en manger, dit l'autre ; va, coquin, va, misérable, ***ne m'approche de ta vie***.

Why not "ne m'approche ***(pas)*** de ta vie" here? Can the "pas" be a random choice here?  One can choose whether or not to insert it in the negative commands like such sentence? Please explain it to me in English, many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Until the 17th century *ne* on its own used to be enough to negate a verb and *pas* was optional. The use of *ne* isolated (without the negative adverb) can still found in **Classical French** (Voltaire, La Fontaine, Molière, etc.) but except in a few cases it has become quite rare nowadays. Nowadays it is the opposite, there is a tendency - mainly in oral language (but nobody knows what the norm will be 200 years from now) - to drop *ne* that has lost part of its negative content and to use *pas* (or other negative adverb, *jamais, plus,* etc.) alone.

**When can *ne* be used alone nowadays?**
In **Modern French** *ne* **can be used alone** only in a limited number of cases. The omission of *pas* is not compulsory, it is considered literary, more or less literary according to frequency.

- With the verbs *cesser, oser, pouvoir, savoir* when followed by an infinitive. It is probably the most frequent case.

  - *Il **ne** cesse de me harceler pour savoir quand je vais venir*.
    *Je **ne** peux/puis te le dire maintenant*.
    *Je **ne** saurais dire pourquoi.*
- With the verbs *daigner, manquer* it is also possible but less frequent.

  - *Il **ne** manque de me rendre visite à chaque fois qu'il vient en France.*
- In a conditional clause starting with  *si*. Quite literary.

  - *Il **ne** pouvait pas s'endormir si je **ne** l'avais embrassé*. (René Bazin *De toute son âme* - 1897).
    This is very literary, and most people will use *pas*. It is more frequent though in the phrases: *si je ne m’abuse*, *si je ne me trompe*.
- In negative questions with an affirmative meaning starting with *qui*. Quite literary.

  - Qui **ne** rêve de faire un jour le tour du monde ?
- When the verb is followed by an adverbial phrase of time meaning *jamais*. Quite literary.

  - *Je **n'** avais de toutes ces années pensé que je reviendrais en France*.

*Ne* is **always used alone** in some fixed phrases: *qu’à cela ne tienne, n’avoir de cesse, ne dire mot, il n’importe, on ne peut plus* [plys], *on ne peut moins, on ne peut mieux, etc.*

For reference:

- *[Sentential Negation in French](https://books.google.fr/books?id=R78s0lNxLLIC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=french%20negation%20ne%20on%20its%20own&source=bl&ots=508vM-Iuv4&sig=haBGL7SmDL3xAjxcl-124uVuoi8&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZwN7dxMTVAhWkBcAKHVEtDFYQ6AEIZDAI#v=onepage&q=french%20negation%20ne%20on%20its%20own&f=false)* (Paul Rowlett, 1998)
- BDL
- [Ne pouvant être employé seul](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3907)
- [Ne employé seul](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3906)
- [l'adverbe ne employé seul](http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/O_a_la_negation.htm#_adverbe_ne_employ%C3%A9_seul) (Bertrand Boutin)
- [Formal negation](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/formal-negation/) (lawlessfrench.com)

Comment: Your answer is more convincing and source-rich, amazing. Thanks.

Comment: I just received the following in an informational email from the consulat général de France à Hong Kong et Macao: "Si je ne vote par internet, quelles sont les modalités de vote à l´urne ou par procuration?", so clearly some bureaucrats think it isn't too literary for an email!

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods The sentence you quote has either not been written by a French native or there is a typo made by a hurried employee who forgot the word *pas*. It is not a matter of being literary or not. The *pas*  is compulsory here and *ne* cannot stand on its own to express the negation,  the sentence is a subordinate clause introducing a condition.  Quite the opposite: ***ne*** could be left out (*si je vote pas par internet...*), although that would sound very informal for an official email (omitting *pas* is OK between friends).

Comment: @None, so that's not a conditional clause?

Comment: It's some sort of linguistic fossil :) Notice that originally, "pas" was a reinforcement for "il ne marche pas" (meaning step), like "point" was a reinforcement word to "elle ne coud point", and "goutte" was a reinforcement to "il ne boit goutte". The last one evolved as a half-joke to "il ne voit goutte" which is now idiomatic.

Comment: @wazoox About the adverbs *pas*, *point*, etc... see [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29878/358) and  [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34749/358)

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods What isn't a conditional clause?

Answer (score 4):

*Ne* was [the original negative particle](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25268/pourquoi-y-a-t-il-pas-avec-encore-%C3%A0-la-forme-n%C3%A9gative/25273#25273) and is still present on its own in certain fixed expressions, like *je ne sais quoi*.

In more recent usage (compared to the 12th-century grammaticalization of *pas*, Voltaire is recent!), it doesn't strike me as random, but rather poetic.

It can still be used today with a similar effect; compare its appearance in « [Beau comme le soleil](https://youtu.be/zT82PhaniHA?t=1m41s) », a song from the 1998 musical Notre-Dame de Paris:

> Quand il me serre contre lui
>   
> je voudrais fuir, mais **je ne puis**.

Here the use of *puis* instead of *peux* also reflects the elevated register of a lone *ne*.

Another theory I might propose for that particular usage of Voltaire's is that *de ta vie* could function as a sort of grammaticalized negative particle. That is to say, if *jamais* can complete *ne* in place of *pas*, then it's conceivable that *de ta vie*, which has a similar meaning, could do so too. There is quite a variety of items that can fill that slot, and the *Banque de dépannage linguistique* [article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3907) that Laure links to below shows *de sa vie* being used in the same way:

> Il **n’a de sa vie** imaginé qu’il serait un jour un héros.

But I'm not quite sure I'm interpreting the Voltaire sentence correctly, since the structure could be *approcher quelqu'un de X* instead of *de ta vie* being temporal. Also, in Laure's catalogue below and in the links cited, it's not clear that this phenomenon would be at home in the imperative mood.

Comment: @Laure Hmm... the list of special cases is pretty long, and on the two BDL pages I see that there are even a couple more. Are you sure the usage is stranger than some of those, infrequent though they might be?

Comment: With your edit and the now that you have differentiated this stand alone *ne* with that of *pouvoir* I have no more reservations about your answer.  Omission of *pas* is really a lot lore frequent with *pouvoir*. Some of the other uses of stand alone *ne* are hardly ever met nowadays.

Comment: I do not think we can draw a parallel between  *jamais* and  *de ta vie* serving as a "grammaticalized negative particle" because what we would usually say would be: *ne m'approche pas / plus/ jamais plus/ **de ta vie***, *de ta vie* **would have to stay** alongside whatever second half of the negation we' use. So we are really dealing with the second part of the negation being entirely left out.

Comment: @Laure Indeed, I was considering putting "Nowadays this is not the case: you need to support *de ta vie* with *jamais* anyway" in the draft I had deleted before seeing the BDL page. But on the whole, I'm tempted to think that grammaticalization is a reliable explanation, since it accounts for so many of the negation completers now. Maybe this one didn't catch on... but it might be how it worked in Voltaire's time, in any case.