# Négation avec « point »

Tags: négation

Je crois que *point* exprime plus fortement la négation que *pas*. *Il n'étudie point* n'a pas le même sens avec *Il n'étudie pas*. Je pense que la différence ressemble à celle entre *not* et *not at all* en anglais.

A/ Pourquoi ne peut-on plus employer point ?

B/ Je demande aussi si *Il n'étudie pas du tout* / *Il n'étudie certainement pas* exprime la même chose comme **Il n'étudie point**.

Comment: Selon le CNRTL, "[point](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/point)" est "Var. vieillie, littér. ou pop. de *pas*"

Comment: Merci. Cependant selon http://www.espacefrancais.com/difference-entre-pas-et-point/ point peut exprimer des nuances que pas ne peut en exprimer.

Comment: Pour "not at all" on dirait plutôt "pas du tout".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Point* n'est plus vraiment utilisé aujourd'hui en France, en dehors d'usages régionaux ou littéraires.

C'est une variante de *pas*, comme *goutte*, *mie* et autres (voir [Why does French use a "split negative"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative/886#886)) mais il n'y a pas de différence d'intensité entre *point* et *pas* (la page de l'espacefrancais.com qui affirme le contraire le fait sans sources et sans convaincre, la phrase censée expliquer le sens de *il n'a pas d'esprit* étant peu idiomatique voire compréhensible : *il n'a rien qui marque dans l'esprit*.

Le sens du verbe utilisé a d'abord dicté quel mot (*pas, point, mie, personne, rien, jamais...*) allait être utilisé pour terminer la négation. Certains se sont généralisés (pas, point, mie) et ont donc perdu leur spécialisation originale alors que d'autres l'ont gardée (personne, rien, jamais, plus...).

Si l'on veut renforcer la négation, on peut ajouter *du tout*, donc *not at all* se traduira par pas du tout et pas par *point*.

J'ai trouvé [une référence](http://gabrielwyler.com/page386.html#Point) qui indique que *point* peut marquer une négation plus soutenue:

> Point appartient surtout à la langue écrite. On se sert de point pour marquer une négation vigoureuse ou pour rompre la monotonie dans une succession de négations.

Le même auteur fait aussi une comparaison entre [pas et point](http://gabrielwyler.com/page377.html#Lacomparaisondepasetpoint) où il ne reprend pas cette affirmation.

Comment: Moi aussi j'ai appris que « point » était plus fort que « pas », l'équivalent peut-être de « en rien ». Je me demande s'il y aurait des textes historiques qui en releveraient (où on en releverait ?) la différence de façon plus claire ...

Comment: @LukeSawczak J'ai trouvé une référence qui mentionne cette différence, mais si elle existe, elle est à mon avis beaucoup plus ténue qu'entre *not* et *not at all*.

Comment: Merci de l'avoir ajoutée en tout cas !

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. Peut-on utiliser **ne...certainement pas** et **ne...nullement pas** au lieu de **pas du tout** ?

Comment: Le premier seulement; : *Il ne viendra certainement pas* qui est différent de *il ne viendra pas du tout* qui sous entend qu'il aurait pu venir "un peu".