# Le cœur a ses raisons que la raison ne connaît POINT

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

In this famous saying by B. Pascal,  *Le cœur a ses raisons que la raison ne connaît point*, what is the meaning of *point*?

Is it just a pun in that  *point*  sounds like *pas* or is it supposed to put emphasis on the phrase just like if one says   "... full stop". Or both?

Comment: Welcome. I think your answer is already [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/n%c3%a9gation-avec-point)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Négation avec « point »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/n%c3%a9gation-avec-point)

Comment: The heart has its reasons which reason knows not. Old-fashioned English to mirror the French. The use of point is well explained below.

Answer (score 5):

If there is pun in this sentence it is on *raison* and not at all on *point*.

If the use of *point* in the negation is considered old-fashioned nowadays, it was usual and common in 17th century writing (*Les Pensées* was published just after Pascal's death in 1669). See this question [Négation avec « point »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/n%C3%A9gation-avec-point) for more about *point*.

The statement plays on the two meanings of the word *raison*. *Les raisons* are the reasons why, the causes and *la raison* is the ability of the mind to think, to make judgements.

This reflects Pascal's religious belief. By this sentence he means we will get a better access to God by following our heart rather than by following our reason.

Answer (score 4):

*Point* is an outdated form of the negation. You can see "ne...point" as an old synonym for "ne...pas". It has disappeared in modern French, but it is still understood when found in proverbs or literary works.

Answer (score 2):

It's another form of negation, it holds the same meaning as "pas" but [stronger.](https://www.espacefrancais.com/difference-entre-pas-et-point/)

Answer (score 2):

*Point* is like *pas*.  It doesn't add any particular emphasis to the sentence.  In modern French, we'd say :

> - Le cœur a ses raisons que la raison ne connaît pas.

When, as early as the 12th century, the negation *ne* had to be reinforced because it had been weakened in spoken French, several words came to play this role such as *pas* (step), *mie* (crumb), *goutte* (drop) and *point* (dot) :

> - Je ne marche pas.
> - Je ne mange mie.
> - Je ne bois goutte.
> - Je ne vois point.

The various adverbs reinforcing the negation *ne* lost their lexical meaning very early on in Old French and did not necessarilly match semantically the verbs they were used with as explained in Eauquidort's remarks.

*Pas* has now superseded all the others and is the most widely used to reinforce or even to replace altogether *ne*.  *Point* is considered literary or a regionalism.  I remember an older guy from Ardèche telling me in conversation about the road police, *Les gendarmes, j'en ai point vu*.

Comment: You can also think of the popular song "La bonne du curé", which makes fun of a provincial old lady: "j'voudrais bien, mais j'peux point".

Comment: Note that's there's no point in recorded history where the negators matched their verbs in semantics in the way you did here. It's often assumed that's how they started, but the negative reinforcers were already used in Latin, already often paired with verbs with no semantic links with their reinforced negator.

Comment: A common citation is Plautus' "quoi neque paratast gutta certi consilii" -That you've not prepared a drop of a solid counsel"

Comment: This is not exactly to the point, but I'm wondering whether "en" is used properly in *Les gendarmes, j'en ai point vu.* I would use "les" instead of "en" here, is that wrong?

Comment: It depends on the underlying sentence, I guess :" je n'ai pas vu les gendarmes" or " je n'ai pas vu de gendarmes".  Both are possible, I think.