# L'abscence d'un article défini dans « Personne n'a dit mot »

Tags: grammaire, négation, formulation

Bonjour,

Quelle règle justifie la phrase suivante ?

> Personne n'a dit mot

À première vue, j'aurais tendance à dire qu'il manque un « un », et donc j'aurais dit

> Personne n'a dit un mot

mais il me semble que la première phrase est quand même bien employée, peut-être plus souvent d'une façon littéraire. Ou peut-être que je me trompe et en fait il n'y a aucune raison de penser que cette formulation soit interdite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cela s'explique par la « règle de l'expression figée », qui a une très vaste « application ». Les expression mises en caractères gras (par user LPH) ci-dessous sont des expressions figées.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mot)) 2. [Mot en général associé à une négation (sans, ne... (pas), équivaut à rien)]
> ♦ **Sans mot dire, sans dire mot; ne dire mot**. Sans rien dire, ne rien dire.
> • Il allait jusqu'à s'appliquer à être un convive agréable. Lui qui eût voulu pouvoir rester sans mot dire, bouche bée devant Mahaut, il se torturait l'esprit pour parler à ses voisines (Radiguet,Bal,1923, p.94).
> • Nous demeurâmes longtemps sans mot dire dans l'obscurité devenue profonde, les yeux fixés sur la mer. Le sentiment du temps s'envolait pour moi (Gracq,Syrtes,1951, p.164).

Il n'y a donc aucune erreur, « Personne n'a dit mot » se dit.

Il est intéressant de remarquer que ce n'est pas employé dans la langue parlée, ou peu, et que l'expression non littéraire «  ne pas piper mot » a dernièrement pris le dessus dans le texte, ce qui ne la rend toujours pas littéraire.

[image]

Comment: Ah oui le bon vieux règle de l'expression figée ! Merci pour le contexte et les autres détails aussi.

Comment: Suivant [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=n%27a+dit+mot%2Cn%27a+pas+pip%C3%A9+mot%2Cqui+ne+dit+mot%2Cqui+ne+dit+mot+consent&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3), "qui ne dit mot" apparaît encore plus souvent, essentiellement à cause du proverbe cité par @None :  "qui ne dit mot consent".

Answer (score 7):

Les deux se disent mais s'analysent grammaticalement de façon différente.

**Personne n'a dit un mot.** : le GN *un mot* est COD de *dire*. On pourrait avoir un autre GN à la place de *un mot* : *une phrase, une parole,* etc.

**Personne n'a dit mot** : *mot* est ici « complément de la négation *ne*<sup>1</sup> ». L'**explication historique** de ce fait figure déjà sur FL dans [l'excellente réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/886/358) de @Unfrancophone à l'occasion d'une autre question. J'en reproduis ici un passage extrait du *Bon usage* :

> La forme atone *ne*, négation ordinaire dans la langue du moyen âge, a été de très bonne heure renforcée par des noms désignant une petite quantité, une petite étendue, une chose de valeur insignifiante : *pas, point, mie, goutte, **mot***<sup>2</sup>, *noix, pois, espi, dé, bouton, denier, pomme, grain, cive, fétu, ail,* etc. [...] Les plus fréquents de ces compléments ont perdu leur valeur propre pour devenir de simples auxiliaires de la négation.

La question [Négation avec « point »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29877/358) sur FL aborde aussi le même sujet.

En ce qui concerne *mot*, le *Bon usage* précise que :

> *Mot*, s'emploie après *dire, répondre, sonner, souffler* : *Qui ne dit* MOT consent. *Il ne souffle* MOT.

On pourra facilement rapprocher l'expression [*ne dire mot*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_dire_mot) de [*n’y voir goutte*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%E2%80%99y_voir_goutte), où « goutte » joue le même rôle que « mot » après les verbes *voir, entendre et comprendre*. Il me semble que *ne dire mot* est d'un usage plus fréquent (donc un peu moins littéraire) que *n'y voir goutte*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Expression employée dans *Le bon usage* dans le chapitre sur les adverbes de négation.</sup>
<sup><sup>1</sup> C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>