# Why is the 'pas' in n'importe quoi dropped?

Tags: étymologie, négation, histoire

As an A2 level learner in a foreign country, we were taught that it is imperative to keep the '*pas*' in negations, and it's okay to drop the '*ne*' in spoken French. But, I observe that the case is exactly the opposite with the phrase "*n'importe quoi*". Why is the '*pas*' left out there?

While doing my research, I did come across [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26715/why-is-the-pas-here-left-out/26719#26719) related question, but all it does is explain that there are certain phrases where the *pas* is dropped without giving any justification about why it is so or how they came to be.

Please do enlighten me if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: *N'importe quoi* is to be linked to *il n'importe* in the related answer: *Ne* is always used alone in some fixed phrases: *qu’à cela ne tienne, n’avoir de cesse, ne dire mot, il n’importe, on ne peut plus , on ne peut moins, on ne peut mieux,* etc. These phrases have been **fixed** by usage. I expect for most French people *importe* in this phrase is hardly seen as a negated verb, but rather as a phrase meaning "anything" or "nonsense", according to the context.

Comment: **N'importe quoi** is an idiomatic and much used phrase in spoken French,. The meaning is basically: Whatever.  Languages have tons of phrases like this. It is usually used as a retort to a situation in a conversation.

Comment: @None This is a request for further clarification. From your comment, I understand that this phrase started out as a negation of importer and somewhere along the line became a phrase fixed by usage. In such a case, there must be a reason why the 'pas' got dropped out, say for example, for convenience of pronunciation. What I am looking for is that reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such phrases as *n'importe quoi*, *n'importe qui*, *n'importe lequel*, *n'importe comment*, etc. *n'importe* is not part of a verbal phrase. Even if French dictionaries list those phrases under *importer*, they categorize them as indefinite phrases (noun or adjective). Therefore one cannot expect to reason in verb terms, it is not an imperative (cf. your question), it is neither negative nor affirmative.

As far as I can tell we can follow the trail from *importer* (i.e. *avoir de l'importance*) :  *ça m’importe* // *il m'importe peu/pas/guère*.  On to the use in the subjunctive  with *qu'importe* and then to *n'importe lequel/qui...* that I expect might be deconstructed as *il ne m'importe pas lequel choisir*. I am not a historian, I can only infer from what I've read so far.

To answer the question in you comment here is the most [comprehensive paper](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2010-2-page-109.htm) I could find on the subject<sup>1</sup> (see 4. LE PROCESSUS DE FORMATION DE *N’IMPORTE QUEL*).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  Pescarini, Sandrine. « N'importe qu- : diachronie et interprétation », *Langue française*, vol. 166, no. 2, 2010, pp. 109-131.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[None's comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50544/why-is-the-pas-in-nimporte-quoi-dropped#comment104953_50544) promoted to an answer:

N'importe quoi is to be linked to *il n'importe* in the related answer: Ne is always used alone in some fixed phrases: *qu’à cela ne tienne, n’avoir de cesse, ne dire mot, il n’importe, on ne peut plus , on ne peut moins, on ne peut mieux,* etc.

These phrases have been **fixed** by usage. I expect for most French people *importe* in this phrase is hardly seen as a negated verb, but rather as a phrase meaning "anything" or "nonsense", according to the context.