# Est-ce qu' on peux utiliser "ne" sans "pas" comme négatif?

Tags: négation

Par exemple:

> [autour de Boris Johnson, les rangs des rebelles ne cessent de grossir](https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2022/07/06/royaume-uni-autour-de-boris-johnson-les-rangs-des-rebelles-ne-cessent-de-grossir_6133514_3210.html) -- *le Monde*

Dans ce contexte ça veux dire sûrement "ne cesse pas de grossir".

Et j'avais pensé moi aussi que le "pas" dans une phrase (surtout à l'oral) est un peux optionnel, comme dans l'exemple ci-dessus -- ce qui est l'inverse de [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/50544/5753):

> we were taught that it is imperative to keep the 'pas' in negations, and it's okay to drop the 'ne' in spoken French

Mais ces réponses ...

- https://french.stackexchange.com/a/138/5753
- https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6605/5753

... indiquent que le "ne" sans "pas" n'est pas négatif? Ou pas forcément négatif?

Comment: Réponse courte, oui. Ce sont souvent des expressions figées (comme "si je ne me trompe" par ex.)